# Issue with labels

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-label

I am writing a program such that a user can enter his details one window and a new window comes showing the output. But, for some reason, the labels in the second window are not being printed.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()    
window.title("Login")
window.geometry("500x500")
window.resizable(0,0)
l = Label(window, text="Name: ", font="Roman 20 bold",padx=10,pady=10)
l.grid(row=0,column=0)
l = Label(window, text="Password: ", font="Roman 20 bold",padx=10,pady=10)
l.grid(row=1,column=0)
e1 = Entry(window, font="Roman 20 bold")
e1.grid(row=0,column=1)
e2 = Entry(window, font="Roman 20 bold",show="*")
e2.grid(row=1,column=1)

def test():
    a= e1.get()
    b= e2.get()
    mess = Tk()
    mess.title("Output")
    mess.geometry("500x500")
    mess.resizable(0,0)

m= StringVar()
m.set("Name: "+a)
l = Label(mess, textvariable=m, font="Roman 20 bold",padx=10,pady=10)
l.grid()

n= StringVar()
n.set("Password: "+b)
l = Label(mess, textvariable=n, font="Roman 20 bold",padx=10,pady=10)
l.grid(row=1,column=0)
mess.mainloop()

b = Button(window,text="Click",font="Roman 15 bold",width=15,command= test)
b.grid(row=2,column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

I don't think it is an issue with the get() method as I am able to print the values obtained on the Python shell screen. So, I think it might be an issue with the label(), though I might be wrong.

Comment: Your issue has been asked in SO several times.

Comment: move `m=StringVar()` to `l.grid()` inside the test function (indent). Also, change `mess = Tk()` -> `mess=Toplevel(window)` and remove `mess.mainloop()`

Comment: The [answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58826378/5317403) may help.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't updating the labels with `l.configure(text="Password: " + c")` so it takes the value that was set at the start which is none.

Also you defined b as the button so you have to define the entry get as another.

Also I deleted the string car because I found it unnecessary.

Updated code:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()    
window.title("Login")
window.geometry("500x500")
window.resizable(0,0)
l = Label(window, text="Name: ", font="Roman 20 bold",padx=10,pady=10)
l.grid(row=0,column=0)
l = Label(window, text="Password: ", font="Roman 20 bold",padx=10,pady=10)
l.grid(row=1,column=0)
e1 = Entry(window, font="Roman 20 bold")
e1.grid(row=0,column=1)
e2 = Entry(window, font="Roman 20 bold",show="*")
e2.grid(row=1,column=1)


def test():
    a = e1.get()
    c = e2.get()
    mess = Tk()
    mess.title("Output")
    mess.geometry("500x500")
    mess.resizable(0,0)
    l2 = Label(mess, font="Roman 20 bold",padx=10,pady=10)
    l2.grid()

    l = Label(mess, font="Roman 20 bold",padx=10,pady=10)
    l.grid(row=1,column=0)
    l.config(text="Password: " + c)
    l2.config(text="Name: " + a)
    mess.mainloop()


b = Button(window,text="Click",font="Roman 15 bold",width=15,command= test)
b.grid(row=2,column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: This will gave `NameError` because `mess` is local.